# ExtensionLibrary ApplicationLayout grid column class setting?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, grid-layout

When using the Extension Library ApplicationLayout control with the new Bootstrap features.  I would like to know how best to override the grid column settings.  Currently they are:

Left Facet 2 column,Middle Facet 8 column, Right Facet 2 column

the CSS classes are

```
    col-md-2 applayout-column-left
    col-md-8 applayout-column-middle
    col-md-2 applayout-column-right
```

I do not see a way I can change this in the ApplicationLayout control properties.

In the meantime, using JavaScript on Client Load, I'm able to change it with the following JavaScript with Dojo help:

```
    dojo.removeClass(document.getElementsByClassName('applayout-content')[0],"col-md-8");
    dojo.addClass(document.getElementsByClassName('applayout-content')[0],"col-md-7");
    dojo.removeClass(document.getElementsByClassName('applayout-column-right')[0] ,"col-md-2");
    dojo.addClass(document.getElementsByClassName('applayout-column-right')[0],'col-md-3');
```

Comment: This was raised to me by someone at ConnectED last month. We hope to implement a way to customise the width of the three facets in a future extlib release

Answer (score 1):

I have found it easier to skip the application layout control and do my own "rows" but if that is not an option you can add your own rows and columns to the main content facet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">Left</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">Middle</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">Right</div>
        </div>
        <xe:this.configuration>
            <xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration></xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration>
        </xe:this.configuration>
    </xe:applicationLayout>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to experiment with that.  For reference, I'm using a one xpage application design pattern with dynamic content for each of the facets which I've tried wrapping with div's at the XPage level.  The div's get rendered inside the dynamic content div into the browser.